# How do I join these two SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I'm using MySQL and MSSql and I'm trying to join these two queries together.

Query 1

```
(SELECT REP.REP_NUM, REP.FIRST_NAME, REP.LAST_NAME
FROM REP, CUSTOMER)
```

Query 2

```
(SELECT CUSTOMER.REP_NUM, SUM(CUSTOMER.BALANCE) AS REP_BALANCE
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.REP_NUM)
```

I've seen you can treat these as two Tables and join them but I'm having trouble getting it to work. The way I was trying to join them I'd get aggregate errors from trying to select the rep first and last name while using the balance sum.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R.REP_NUM, R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME
FROM REP r
inner join
(SELECT c.REP_NUM, SUM(c.BALANCE) AS REP_BALANCE
FROM CUSTOMER c
GROUP BY c.REP_NUM) t
on r.rep_num = t.rep_num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.REP_NUM, r.FIRST_NAME, r.LAST_NAME, SUM (c.BALANCE) AS REP_BALANCE
FROM   REP r
       INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c ON r.REP_NUM = c.REP_NUM
GROUP BY r.REP_NUM, r.FIRST_NAME, r.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: That worked perfectly I was just aliasing my code like that but only grouped by one vale grouping by all the multiples should work since I just had output with many multiples.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT REP.REP_NUM, REP.FIRST_NAME, REP.LAST_NAME 
FROM REP join(
SELECT CUSTOMER.REP_NUM, SUM(CUSTOMER.BALANCE) AS REP_BALANCE 
FROM CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.REP_NUM
) as B on some_condition...
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
select a.REP_NUM,a.FIRST_NAME,a.LAST_NAME,b.REP_NUM,Sum(b.BALANCE) as REP_BALANCE from REP a as inner join CUSTOMER b on a.REP_NUM=b.REP_NUM group by b.REP_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select New.REP_NUM,New.FIRST_NAME,New.LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER.REP_NUM, 
    SUM(CUSTOMER.BALANCE) AS REP_BALANCE 
    from (SELECT REP.REP_NUM, REP.FIRST_NAME, REP.LAST_NAME
    FROM REP, CUSTOMER) New
    inner join CUSTOMER  ON CUSTOMER.REP_NUM=New.REP_NUM
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER.REP_NUM
```